# ARM DS-5 development studio cannot start

Tags: eclipse, arm, ds-5

I have installed ARM DS-5 on my PC (Windows 10 64-bi); When launching Eclipse I got an error message:

**Could not read environment file C:...\ds5\win_64\r5p0-27rel0\sw\info\env.ini": Operation not permitted**

I have Full Control of this env.ini file and can open it with notepad to read/write; So not really a file permission issue.

Any idea why Eclipse cannot start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I don't have the "Personal" registry key set in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders".

A workaround is to set the environment variable "MY_DOCS" to point to "My Documents" folder.